# htaccess Dynamic Folder and Filename to Match RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

A link `http://localhost/myproject/payment/confirm/1` has been redirected to `http://localhost/myproject/payment/confirm.php?id=1` by this rule:

```
# myproject   : root folder
# payment     : folder myproject/payment
# confirm.php : file in myproject/payment/confirm.php 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} confirm/(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)$ $1\.php?id=$2 [L]
```

A PHP file can be located in different folder path or depth. For example A link `http://localhost/myproject/client/payment/confirm/1` also works with rule above to be rewrite to `http://localhost/myproject/client/payment/confirm.php?id=1`.

I'm trying to make `confirm` be dynamic for other pages, for example `invoice/2` to `invoice.php?id=2`.

I tried to include `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` in the second RewriteCond but no luck.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)$ $1\.php?id=$2 [L]
```

How to achieve this so that we shouldn't define long possible pages that has id on it? Please advice.

Comment: The contents of REQUEST_URI and REQUEST_FILENAME are pretty much dependent on each other at this point, so what you tried to check there, does not make much sense. The second RewriteCond was rather superfluous in your first version already - the RewriteRule itself is perfectly capable of checking against the URL _path_. But now you don’t even want that check any more. What happens when you just leave out that second condition completely?

Comment: @CBroe Yes I think I'm not in the right direction. I want to make pretty URL (without .php) with dynamic file path and may have `/id` on its tail. So it could be `http://localhost/myproject/folder/folder/file/id` or `http://localhost/myproject/folder/file` or `http://localhost/myproject/folder/file/id` or `http://localhost/myproject/folder/folder/file`.

Comment: Then you will have to check two different possibilities - that the requested URL with `.php` appended matches an existing PHP file, or that the requested URL with the `/id` part _removed first_, and then getting `.php` appended, matches an existing PHP file.

Comment: @CBroe I define all custom path possibilities for consistency and flexibility. Thanks for the enlightenment.